# How to apply a color overlay in Lottie

Tags: ios, objective-c, lottie

How to apply color overlay on an animation? I have a pretty simple single color icons. And I want to make them usable in dark mode without rerendering in After Effects with different colors. I saw examples in docs:

```
let redValueProvider = ColorValueProvider(Color(r: 1, g: 0.2, b: 0.3, a: 1))
animationView.setValueProvider(redValueProvider, keypath: AnimationKeypath(keypath: "Switch Outline Outlines.**.Fill 1.Color"))
animationView.setValueProvider(redValueProvider, keypath: AnimationKeypath(keypath: "Checkmark Outlines 2.**.Stroke 1.Color"))
```

But I don't understand how to implement it. The Objective C fork of Lottie doesn't have ColorValueProvider class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen ([request](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/issues/1005) and [docs](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/ios?id=value-providers)) there is no "support" for dark mode.

Maybe something like this one helps ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
    let keypath = AnimationKeypath(keys: ["Switch Outline Outlines", "**", "Fill 1", "Color"])
    let colorProvider: ColorValueProvider
    if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
       colorProvider = ColorValueProvider(UIColor.white.lottieColorValue)
       animationView.setValueProvider(colorProvider, keypath: keypath)
    } else {
       colorProvider = ColorValueProvider(UIColor.black.lottieColorValue)
       animationView.setValueProvider(colorProvider, keypath: keypath)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. and call this method when day-night mode changed.

```
@implementation LOTAnimationView (tintColor)

- (void)updateColor:(UIColor *)color {
    NSArray *keypaths = [self keysForKeyPath:[LOTKeypath keypathWithString:@"**"]];
    
    LOTColorValueCallback *colorCallback = [LOTColorValueCallback withCGColor:color.CGColor];
    for (NSString *keyPathStr in keypaths) {
        LOTKeypath *keypath = [LOTKeypath keypathWithString:[keyPathStr stringByAppendingString:@".Color"]];
        [self setValueDelegate:colorCallback forKeypath:keypath];
    }
}

@end
```